# Analytic proof for the convergence of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

$f_{n}$  is  a  sequence  of  functions  that  converges to  a  function  $f$ . Now  a  sequence  is  defined  from  this  by $g_{n}$ = max$\{$ min $(f_{n},g)$,-g$\}$.

Now  geometrically  what  is  seen  is  the  parts  of $\{f_{n}\}$'s  that  are  within  the  region  bounded  by  $g$  and $-g$  joined  by  the  parts  of  $g$  cut by $f_{n}$  are  the  $g_{n}$'s.Now given  that $|f(x)|\le g(x)$  the  sequence  $g_{n}$  tends  to  $f$ . I  have  drawn  this.

[image]

So  I  can see  geometrically  the  sequence $\{g_{n}\}$ tends  to  the  function  $f$. Only for writing  the  proof  analytically  is  I  need  some  lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x$ define $$\phi_x(t)=\begin{cases} g(x),&(t>g(x)),
\\t,&(-g(x)\le t\le g(x)),
\\-g(x),&(t<-g(x)).\end{cases}$$

Then $g_n(x)=\phi_x( f_n(x))$. Since $\phi_x$ is continuous, $g_n(x)\to\phi_x(f(x))$. And $|f|\le g$ shows that $\phi_x(f(x))=f(x)$.